# How to logout customer

Tags: magento-1.9, logout

I am trying to logout user

I used following code

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout();
?>
```

But it's not working

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Have you check your mage.php file is called or not? you can first check using echo inside mage.php and check its call or not ?

Comment: Jatin,where you want to call this code? and why?

Comment: I want to logout user in. `<magentohost>/logout.php` @AmitBera

Comment: @Rakesh `mage.php` is called

Comment: I am trying to to create `login` web service, I created it I got `token` and `token secret` but when I login, I am not able to get another users `token` and `token secret` that's why I want to logout manually. @AmitBera

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Jatin,you have do some mistakes.**

- First,need to set Current store for which you want to set session
  logout.so Change `Mage::app();` to `Mage::app('default');` // assume that
  you have only one store
- Second,you need to add  `Mage::getSingleton("core/session",
  array("name" => "frontend"));` code after *Mage::app();* for  inlize
  session for the file logout.php
- Also ,you need to carry session to logout.php